# HiveQL/SQL: What is the difference between CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS) and CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE + INSERT INTO?

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

I know of two ways to create tables that seem to produce the same result: a table. What is the difference between the two methods and which method is optimal in terms of best practices? The two methods are shown below:

Method 1:

```
CREATE TABLE db.tablename1 STORED AS ORC AS
SELECT *
FROM db.tablename2;
```

Method 2:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.tablename1
    id STRING,
    var2 STRING
)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION '/dir/';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE db.tablename1
SELECT * FROM db.tablename2;
```

Method 2 requires more code and achieves the same result. Why would anyone use method 2? For context, Some data scientists at my company opt to create tables using method 2.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is more the "fast-and-dirty" method.  It does not provide control much over the table structure, such as:

- Data types
- Default values
- Additional (unset) columns
- Partitioning
- Cluster keys
- Constraints

Note that some of these may be supported by CTAS (the first solution) but usually the focus is on the `select` part of the query and not the table.

Creating the table first and then inserting into it means that the table can be fully defined.